# Перенаправление в .htaccess для ЧПУ

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Настраиваю ЧПУ с помощью .htaccess. (пока на локалке).
Заменил index.php?id=# на page# следующим образом:

```
RewriteRule ^/?page([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

Все отрабатывает. То есть, .htaccess подключен корректно и работает. Теперь хочу "склеить"  полученные страницы с изначальными. То есть, перенаправить с id# на page#. Не получается.

Для примера, беру только страницу с id=0 и делаю так:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.loc\/index\.php?id=0$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.loc/page0$1 [R=301,L]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка в строках выше.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте такой реврайт

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://site.loc/page%1? [R=301,L]
```

Первое условие пропускает только обращение к `index.php` в корне, второе условие добавляет фильтрацию по `GET` параметру `id=ЧИСЛО`. Знак вопроса на конце реврайта нужен чтобы убрать `GET` параметры.

P.S. Вот думаю, не получится ли у вас зацикливание этих двух реврайтов. P.P.S. Хотя, раз файл `index.php` у вас есть на сервере, при прямом обращении к нему в виде `index.php?id=ЧИСЛО`, реврайт срабатывать не будет. Вопрос не имеет смысла, как и ответ :)

Comment: Попробовал. Признаков перенаправления на сайте не появилось, все отрабатывает по старым урлам. Хотя Ваш ответ звучит очень логично.

Comment: Смотрите мой P.P.S. Раз файл есть, то идет прямое обращение к нему, а не обработка реврайтов в .htaccess.

Comment: Судя по всему, Вы правы. Происходит зацикливание. Напрямую через .htaccess наверное не выйдет. Буду искать подходы на PHP. Если можете, посоветуйте доходчивый линк по реализации ЧПУ с использованием PHP.

Comment: Я бы вам предложил на всех страницах указать канонический URL, тогда с поисковиками проблем не будет. Если же все-таки хотите редирект, то переименуйте файл index.php в index2.php, тогда все прямые запросы к старому файлу будут обрабатываться реврайтом из-за его отсутствия.А по поводу чпу на php, вот :) https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%87%D0%BF%D1%83+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы избежать зацикливания, нужно использовать дополнительный параметр.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Проксируем с доп. параметром "z"
# В принципе, флаг [P] не является обязательным
RewriteRule ^/?page([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1&z [P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+) [NC]
# Не редиректим, если в конце запроса найден доп. параметр "z"
# Так мы избегаем зацикливания
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !z$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /page%1? [R=301,L]
```

Данные правила перенаправят страницу: `http://site.loc/index.php?id=14` на `http://site.loc/page14` и не тронут страницу вида `http://site.loc/index.php?id=14&z`.

Comment: Все равно работать не будет, пока файл index.php существует на сервере физически.