# Как создать правило для преобразования ссылок?

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите, как создать правило преобразования ссылок вида

```
http://www.url.ru/kommercheskaya/arenda_i_prodazha/число-v_nalichii/?id=число1&build=число2
```

в ссылки вида:

```
http://www.url.ru/kommercheskaya/arenda_i_prodazha/число-v_nalichii/число2/число1/
```

Как пример, из ссылки вида

```
http://www.url.ru/kommercheskaya/arenda_i_prodazha/27214-v_nalichii/?id=219261&build=2211
```

получить

```
http://www.url.ru/kommercheskaya/arenda_i_prodazha/27214-v_nalichii/2211/219261/
```

Comment: Как пример,
из ссылки вида
http://www.url.ru/kommercheskaya/arenda_i_prodazha/27214-v_nalichii/?id=219261&build=2211
получить
http://www.url.ru/kommercheskaya/arenda_i_prodazha/27214-v_nalichii/2211/219261/

Comment: Немного отформатировал ваш вопрос.

Comment: А зачем вам это надо? Вы меняете ссылки старого вида на новые для 301 редиректа?

Comment: Visman, да. Во-первых это чпу ссылка плюс надо сделать 301 редирект со старых на новые. Перепробовал куча вариантов из  гугла, не получается (

Comment: Если у вас по старым ссылкам лежат реальные файлы, то правила переадресации на них работать не будут.

Comment: Тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442891/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-htaccess-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3/442912#442912 можете мой ответ посмотреть. Вопрос там похож.

Comment: Visman, а можете без переадресации подсказать как составить правило. В принципе может и без переадресации обойтись, так как старые ссылки у нас не индексировались (были закрыты в роботсе)

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать такой редирект:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&build=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\/)$ http://www.url.ru/$1%1/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

Он несколько шире вашего запроса. Срабатывает при наличии параметров вида `id=ЧИСЛО&build=ЧИСЛО` и при окончании строки запроса на слеш. То есть для

```
http://www.url.ru/непередаваемынаборсимволов/?id=219261&build=2211
```

сработает, а для

```
http://www.url.ru/непередаваемынаборсимволов/бах?id=219261&build=2211
```

не сработает.

**UPD**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(gif|jpg|css|png|swf|js|ico|pdf|txt|xml|zip|ttf|eot|svg|woff))$ $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&build=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\/)$ url.ru/$1%1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^.+\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/$ index.php?id=$1&build=$2 [L]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Ваши правила переадресации + мой ответ + дополнительное правило для передачи переменных `id` и `build` в обработчик из `index.php`.

Если работать не будет, то возможно обработчик в php коде нужно под новые правила переписывать.

Comment: редирект работает, но вылетает ошибка 404, то есть сама страница не перемещается на новые ссылки :(

Comment: А у вас обработчик для ЧПУ (человеко-понятных урлов) существует? В .htaccess какие-нибудь правила переадресации были до этого?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(gif|jpg|css|png|swf|js|ico|pdf|txt|xml|zip|ttf|eot|svg|woff))$ $1 [L] 
#####

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&build=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\/)$ http://www.url.ru/$1%1/%2/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: @Eugene84, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Visman, спасибо. Все равно ошибка 404. А переадресация работает.